# jQuery Isotope with text for every filter

Tags: jquery, filtering, jquery-isotope

I'm using jQuery Isotope with filter method: http://isotope.metafizzy.co/demos/filtering.html

I would like to add an additional function when you click on a filter: a p text that shows up, different for each filter.

For now, I can only bring up the same text. I want to know how to create a different one for each category, which is shown only when you click on the filter, here's my jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/itzuki87/Xy5pZ/

```
var $container = $('#container');
$container.isotope({
});

$('#filters a').click(function(){
 var selector = $(this).attr('data-filter');
  $(".text_category").slideUp(500);
  $(".text_category").slideDown(500);
 $container.isotope({ filter: selector });
return false;
});
```

Can anyone help me? Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could use class added in data-filter in p, like

```
<li><a href="#" data-filter="*">show all</a></li>
<li><a href="#" data-filter=".metal">metal</a></li>
<li><a href="#" data-filter=".transition">transition</a></li>
```

And paragraphs

```
<p class="text_category hide" data-category="*">
Donec auctor faucibus libero ...
</p>
<p class="text_category hide" data-category=".metal">
metal para
</p>
<p class="text_category hide" data-category=".transition">
transition para content here
</p>
```

And js

```
$('#filters a').click(function(){
  var selector = $(this).attr('data-filter');
    alert(selector);
    $(".text_category").hide();  //hide all p's
    $("p[data-category='"+selector+"']").slideUp(500); //show respective
    $("p[data-category='"+selector+"']").slideDown(500);
    $container.isotope({ filter: selector });
    return false;
});
```

Demo: [Updated Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Xy5pZ/3/)

Comment: I tried but it will not let me put the vote up because I'm new to Stack Overlow (Vote Up requires 15 reputation and I have 0), I do everything by on my own with several trial and errors, I ask for help only as a last hope :) I must correctly answer at least one question but here it seems that they are all better than me!

Answer (score 0):

you could check the selector with a if statement, then change the text with an ajax script that replace the html of the div containing the text, or to actually print every div and hide/show them via jQuery.